# Remove Slug Custom post type error! Sowing this error when added new custom post

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Please help me I'm facing this when I have added new post

```
****Remove Slug Custom post type error!****
    **.htaccess is not writable, please add following lines to complete your 
    installation:** 
    RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^rooms/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^spilleautomater/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^kurs/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What are you installing? I ask this because these rewrite rules seem strange to me.

Comment: I have installed this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type/

Comment: After installing this plugin getting this error..but adding post work perfect..just want to not display this error when adding posts..

Comment: The cause of the error is that the plugin could not re-write the .htaccess file in your html folder. It is asking you to manually edit that file and add these lines. I would definitely save a backup copy before doing any editing. I am not a Apache mod_rewrite expert but some of these rules (the first four and the last one) seem strange to me.

Comment: Be very careful with rewrite rules - doing something wrong can easily change a working site into a completely non working site. Always make a copy of the working .htaccess file before changing it.

Comment: I have added these code in .htaccess file.. The error goes but after refresh the post.. the .htaccess code reverted ..

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that your hosting provider doesn't allow you to change the .htaccess file. Do you know the policy of your hosting provider regarding .htaccess files?